# How to fetch the data from multiple tables order by SUM query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have different tables like profiles, tournaments, tournamentdate, tournamentresult and pigeons.

**Profiles columns >** ProfileId, Name, Address, etc. 
**Tournaments columns >** tID, name, detail, startdate, enddate, etc. 
**Tournamentdate columns >** tdID, tID, date. 
**Tournamentresult Columns >** ResultID, ProfileID, tID, tdID, starttime and Total (Total Time). 
**Pigeons Columns >** PID, ResultID, ProfileID, TID, TDID, Pigeon Number, FlyingTime, TotalTime.

I have create a tournament for 3 days like 13,15,17 May (added dates into tournamentdate Table). I have added 5 peoples from Profiles Table, 7 Pigeons a day into Pigeons Table.

I will show you how to I display data using PHP.
[image]

this is one day record one Person have 7 Pigeons I am using SQL Sum Query for each person for total. Now I want to display same thing but Total as DESC.

Here is my code (function.php)

```
function GetTournamentDate($conn, $TID)
{
    $TID = (int)$TID;
    $tournaments = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tournamentdate WHERE `TID`='$TID' ORDER BY `TDate` ASC";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tournaments[] = array(
                'TDID' => $row['TDID'],
                'TID' => $row['TID'],
                'TDate' => $row['TDate'],
            );
        }
    }

    return $tournaments;
}
//=========
function GetResults($conn, $TID)
{
    $TID = (int)$TID;
    $Results = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tournamentresult WHERE `TID`='$TID' ORDER BY `Total` DESC";

    $Result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($Result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Results[] = array(
                'ResultID' => $row['ResultID'],
                'ProfileID' => $row['ProfileID'],
                'TID' => $row['TID'],
                'TDID' => $row['TDID'],
                'StartTime' => $row['StartTime'],
                'Total' => $row['Total'],
                'Price' => $row['Price'],
            );
        }
    }

    return $Results;
}
// ====================
function GetPigeonByResult($conn, $ResultID, $ProfileID, $TDID)
{
    $ResultID = (int)$ResultID;
    $ProfileID = (int)$ProfileID;
    $TDID = (int)$TDID;

    $Results = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pigeons WHERE `ResultID` = '$ResultID' and `ProfileID` = '$ProfileID' and `TDID` = '$TDID' ORDER BY `Pigeon` ASC";

    $Result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($Result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row 
        while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Results[] = array(
                'PigeonID' => $row['PigeonID'],
                'ResultID' => $row['ResultID'],
                'Pigeon' => $row['Pigeon'],
                'PigeonTime' => $row['PigeonTime'],
                'PigeonTotalTime' => $row['PigeonTotalTime'],
                'Status' => $row['Status'],
            );
        }
    }

    return $Results;
}
//=================
// profile_data
function ProfileData($conn, $ProfileID)
{
    $ProfileID = (int)$ProfileID;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        unset($func_get_args[1]);
        // check arry fields
        $valid = array('ProfileID', 'ProfileName', 'ProfileAddress', 'ProfileNumber', 'ProfileDetail');
        $fields = array();
        foreach ($func_get_args as $arg) {
            if (in_array($arg, $valid)) $fields[] = $arg;
        }
        // convert fields
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $fields) . '`';
        $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM profiles WHERE ProfileID = '$ProfileID'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                foreach ($func_get_args as $field) {
                    $func_get_args[$field] = $row[$field];
                }
                return $func_get_args;
            }
        } // else
    }
}
// =================
```

and here in index.php

```
<?php
$TID = 5; // example
$Results = GetResults($conn, $TID);

$TournamentDate = GetTournamentDate($conn, $TID);
if (!empty($TournamentDate)) {
foreach ($TournamentDate as $TD) {
$TDID = $TD['TDID'];
$TDate = $TD['TDate'];
}

$TDID = 8; // example

if (!empty($Results)) {
foreach ($Results as $TR) {
$ResultID = $TR['ResultID'];
$ProfileID = $TR['ProfileID'];
$TotalPigeons = GetPigeonByResult($conn, $ResultID, $ProfileID, $TDID);
    }
}
?>
<tbody>
<?php
$RCount = 0;
foreach ($Results as $Result) {
$RCount++;
$ResultID = $Result['ResultID'];
$ProfileID = $Result['ProfileID'];
$StartTime = $Result['StartTime'];
if ($StartTime == 0) {
$StartTime = '';
} else {
$StartTime = secondsToWords($StartTime);
//  $StartTime = substr($StartTime, 0, -3);
}
$Total = $Result['Total'];
if ($Total == 0) {
$Total = '<p style="color: #ccc">0</p>';
} else {
$Total = secondsToWords($Total);
//   $Total = substr($Total, 0, -3);
}

$ProfileData = ProfileData($conn, $ProfileID, 'ProfileName', 'ProfileAddress');
$ProfileName = $ProfileData['ProfileName'];
$ProfileAddress = $ProfileData['ProfileAddress'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$RCount</td>";
?>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<h3 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
<?php echo $ProfileName; ?>
</h3>
<p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><?php echo $ProfileAddress; ?></p>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#!" class="edit" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $ResultID . '-sTime'; ?>">
<?php echo $StartTime; ?>
</a>
</td>
<?php
// Get Pigeons
$TotalPigeons = GetPigeonByResult($conn, $ResultID, $ProfileID, $TDID);
if (!empty($TotalPigeons)) {
$TotalSum = 0;
foreach ($TotalPigeons as $TP) {
$tPigeonID = $TP['PigeonID'];
$PigeonTime = $TP['PigeonTime'];
$PigeonTotalTime = $TP['PigeonTotalTime'];
$PigeonStatus = $TP['Status'];

$TotalSum = $TotalSum + $PigeonTotalTime;

$tPigeonTime = secondsToWords($PigeonTime);

$PigeonTotalTime = secondsToWords($PigeonTotalTime);

if ($PigeonTime == 0) {
if ($PigeonStatus == 1) {
?>
<td>
<a href="#!" class="edit" data-type="text" data-value="" data-pk="<?php echo $tPigeonID . '-pTime-' . $Result['StartTime'] . '-' . $Result['Total']; ?>">
empty
</a>
<a href="index.php?All=Result&Tournament=<?php echo $TID; ?>&Date=<?php echo $TDID; ?>&PigeonStatusDeactivate=<?php echo $tPigeonID; ?>" style="margin-top: 10px;" role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-xs">Active</a>
</td>
<?php
} else {
?>
<td>
<a href="index.php?All=Result&Tournament=<?php echo $TID; ?>&Date=<?php echo $TDID; ?>&PigeonStatusActivate=<?php echo $tPigeonID; ?>" role="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-xs">Waste</a>
</td>
<?php
}
} else {
if ($PigeonStatus == 1) {
?>
<td>
<a href="#!" class="edit" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $tPigeonID . '-pTime-' . $Result['StartTime'] . '-' . $Result['Total']; ?>">
<?php echo $tPigeonTime; ?>
</a>
<p><small><?php echo $PigeonTotalTime; ?></small></p>
<a href="index.php?All=Result&Tournament=<?php echo $TID; ?>&Date=<?php echo $TDID; ?>&PigeonStatusDeactivate=<?php echo $tPigeonID; ?>" style="margin-top: 10px;" role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-xs">Active</a>
</td>
<?php
} else {
?>
<td style="background-color: red; color: white;">
<a href="index.php?All=Result&Tournament=<?php echo $TID; ?>&Date=<?php echo $TDID; ?>&PigeonStatusActivate=<?php echo $tPigeonID; ?>" role="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-xs">Waste</a>
</td>
<?php
}
}
}
}
echo "<td>" . secondsToWords($TotalSum) . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Please tell me how to I Display as total DESC.  
*If you give me code I will be grateful to you۔*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a SELECT statement to get all the users and inside the SELECT statement you can nest another SELECT to get the total score.
Then you can simply sort your result using ORDER.

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT SUM(score) FROM games WHERE user = users.ID) AS total
FROM users ORDER BY total DESC
```

In your example, if I understand correctly, this would translate to:

```sql
SELECT
    *, (SELECT SUM(TotalTime) FROM Pigeons WHERE ProfileID = Profiles.ProfileId) AS total
FROM Profiles ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group_concat along with group by you can get all data in a single query.
then you can use those data using explode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).